# how to allow CRON to access directory or files?

Tags: php, cron

I've added a cron job to the crontab:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/d1/directory/dir2/script.php
```

It's a script that needs to run everyday. But for now it's running every minute.

I can see that the job is added to the crontab and even saving a record to database. But, it isn't saving an excel file to the directory. But I try to call directly or paste the url and navigate to the script.php using a browser, it generates the file (so it's working).

So my question is how to allow cron to access a directly?

Comment: change the user the cron runs under, or change the file permissions for where you write the file

Comment: `* * * * *` is every minute. Everyday would be: `0 0 * * *` See [crontab.guru](https://crontab.guru/examples.html) for various examples.

Comment: @tim they have the same user, I set the cron in ssh which uses the same credentials in my ftp login.

Comment: @PaulT. I am not in that part yet but thanks anyway, my primary concern is how to make sure that the script will work.

Comment: Oh, I see, you said 'for now' on the CRON time. Would the files happen to be created in the `/usr/bin/php` path, by chance?